# Show table row if a value is present

Tags: php, tabular

I have a file that I scrape with PHP. It has 3 rows and 3 columns and has these values

```
John - 35000 - OL
Adam - 4000 - AF
John - 5000 - XS
```

What I am trying to do is to show only the row(s) that contain(s) the word "John"
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you post some php code regarding your output? -- You can either trim the value and check for equality with "John" (case-sensitive?) or use i.e. `preg_match`

Comment: Here it is [link](http://pastebin.com/fHcagkP6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($rows as $row){
  if(strpos('John') !== false)
    echo $row;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't get it working. My code is [link](http://pastebin.com/fHcagkP6). Where do I add it?

Comment: It works now but it does the direct opposite. It shows all rows but the row that contains John.

Comment: What did you have to change between your second and third comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and [`preg_grep`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

```
// Put the file into an array
$file = file( $file_contents );

// Get only the lines that have John
$john = preg_grep( '~^John~', $file );
```

There are about a million ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

I'd `explode()` the row and check for the first value:

```
$row_array = explode(" - ", $row);

if ($row_array[0] == "John") {
  // Row contains John
} else {
  // Row does not
}
```

Since you are scraping, you can parse the individual values easily since they are in an array.

Comment: afaik strpos($row, 'John') == 0 should be faster than explode

Comment: I know, but since the OP is *scraping* they will be parsing the string later on. `explode()`ing beforehand saves time later on.

Comment: Okay, let me put it this way. Once the OP finds that the row contains `John`, what will happen next? I'd guess that the OP will parse that line and extract the individual pieces. This is just my way of solving the problem, sheesh.

Comment: First of all I am very new to php. In fact this is the first php file I am trying to get to work. Here is the whole code. Where do I add your code? I tried this and all other answers but I still couldn't get it work. [link](http://pastebin.com/fHcagkP6) @jaime